# Are ice tea in bottles considered as carbonated drinks like coke?

Tags: tea, drinks

Are ice tea bottles like Lipton considered to be carbonated drinks like coke and 7up?
I have issues in my GI (Gastro Intestinal) tract and I cannot tolerate coke and other carbonated drinks, I am just wondering if ice tea is a carbonated drink  that might cause me discomfort.

Comment: Can you be more specific, both about which carbohydrates you can't tolerate and which type of ice tea (flavour, diet or not, etc)? Carb/sugar content varies between types. But in general, commercial iced tea contains about as much sugar as soda does.

Comment: @Johanna sorry I made a mistake, I was talking about Carbonated drinks - I edited the question

Comment: Most iced tea is not carbonated; just look at the labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "Soft drink" stems from drinks with No alcohol in them. ice tea is a "Soft drink" But is not carbonated.

Answer (score 4):

Many major brands of iced tea are not carbonated.  However there are a few that are, [such as this brand.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RH6776D) It should specify on the container.